# ambiguous conversion for functional-style cast with complex<double>

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, clang, c++14

I have a MVE program that compiles and runs with g++-5.2.0 but not with clang-602.0.53.  The program tries to assign a lambda expression to a type alias of compatible type.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<complex>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::complex;
// type alias
using CfDD = complex<double> (*) (double);
// lambda of compatible type
auto theLambda = [] (double _) {return complex<double>({1,0});};

int main()
{   // Show that the lambda is callable:
    cout << theLambda(3.14) << endl;
    // Show that the lambda is assignable to a var of type CfDD
    CfDD cfdd = theLambda;
    cout << cfdd (3.14) << endl;
}
```

This program works when compiled with g++-5.2.0:

```
$ g++-5 --version
g++-5 (Homebrew gcc 5.2.0) 5.2.0
   ...
$ g++-5 -std=c++14 main.cpp && ./a.out
(1,0)
(1,0)
```

But produces an error that I don't understand and don't know how to fix under clang:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with- gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
    ...

$ gcc -std=c++14 main.cpp

main.cpp:10:40: error: ambiguous conversion for functional-style cast from 'void' to
  'complex<double>'
auto theLambda = [] (double _) {return complex<double>({1,0});};
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ...      candidate is the implicit move constructor
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY complex<double>
                            ^
    ...      candidate is the implicit copy constructor
candidate constructor
complex<double>::complex(const complex<float>& __c)
```

What does this error mean and why doesn't this code compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you wrote:

```
return complex<double>({1,0});
```

we look at the valid constructors for [`std::complex<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex) and find:

```
constexpr complex(double re = 0.0, double im = 0.0); // (1)

constexpr complex( const complex& other ); // (2)

constexpr complex(const complex<float>& other); // (3a)
explicit constexpr complex(const complex<long double>& other); // (3b)
```

We're constructing this object with an initializer list. So `(1)` isn't viable, and neither is `(3b)` since that constructor is marked `explicit`. The other two, however, are both viable since both `complex<double>` and `complex<float>` can be constructed from two `int`s. Neither is better than the other, which is why clang complains about "ambiguous conversion".

The easiest solution is to drop the unnecessary `{}`s:

```
return complex<double>(1,0);
```

Note that you don't need to name the argument `_`, you can just not provide a name for it.

Comment: I infer from this that the type of `{1, 0}` is void, because the compiler was complaining about conversion of `void` to `complex<double>`, correct?

Comment: @Reb.Cabin The key part of the error is `ambiguous`. The type of that expression doesn't matter.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Braced lists are syntax elements and not fully-fledged expressions, they cannot be said to have a type.